# remove query string and parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following url of a php site that I'd like to remove the query string and parameters using htaccess.

```
https://demo.site.com/html/folder/index.php?page=news
https://demo.site.com/html/folder/index.php?page=one-page-layout&header=default&layout=boxed
```

so that it becomes

```
https://demo.site.com/html/folder/news
https://demo.site.com/html/folder/one-page-layout
```

I have tried out the various solutions provided here but they didn't work.

Here's my full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /html/sandal/index.php?page=pageName to /html/sandal/pageName
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /html/sandal/(?:index.php)?\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /html/sandal/%1? [L,R]
# internally forward /html/sandal/pageName to /html/sandal/index.php?page=pageName

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /html/sandal/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.htaccess` in the `/html/folder` add the following Rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /html/folder/index.php?page=pageName to /html/folder/pageName
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /html/folder/(?:index.php)?\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /html/folder/%1? [L,R]
# internally forward /html/folder/pageName to /html/folder/index.php?page=pageName

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /html/folder/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite `/html/folder/pageName` to `/html/folder/index.php?page=pageName` .

Comment: This doesn't work. Something that I should have pointed out is the root site https://demo.site.com has other htaccess so I need to place the htaccess in https://demo.site.com/html/folder/

Comment: @JoelM Just remove the folder names from the pattern. Ie : change `^html/folder/(.+)/?$` to `^(.+)/?$` if the location of your htaccess is `/html/folder/.htaccess` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is how my htaccess looks like so far: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` But still it doesn't work. Here's the live url. [live url](https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/?page=news).

Comment: Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: @JoelM Please try the updated version and let me know how it works.

Comment: Hi starkeen. We are very close to the solution. Now what happens is the first time I go to the home page https://demo.site.com/html/folder/index.php then navigate to https://demo.site.com/html/folder/index.php?page=news it changes the url to https://demo.site.com/html/folder/news. However, if I attempt to navigate to another page like about us it shows the url as https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/news?page=about-us

Comment: @JoelM Try visiting https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/index.php?page=about-us 
or https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/?page=about-us . Both URLs are working as expected with the rule  I think.

Comment: The first time when you visit the page it shows correctly. Example: go to https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/index.php?page=about-us, then go to the menu Pages > Our History, you'll see the url is now https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/about-us?page=our-history

Comment: So basically we need to add an OR option whereby it can also check if there's no index.php to replace just "?page=" and the preceding 'about-us' to make the URL https://demo.arrowthemes.com/html/sandal/our-history

Comment: @JoelM Please post your full htaccess in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I think we are very close to getting a solution. I updated the original question with the full htacces

Comment: @JoelM I updated the pattern of the second  rewrite rule. Try the updated rule and let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: If the updated code doesn't solve your issue then try adding the following 2 lines before your other rules but bellow `RewriteEngine on` 

########

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /html/sandal/.+/?\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.+$ /html/sandal/%1? [L,R]`


This will redirect your urls from `/html/sandal/page/?page=foobar` to `/html/sandal/foobar` .

Comment: Bravo. After adding the two lines you mentioned, it now works. Thanks a lot.